# Long format data: Calculate NA for year x as row mean of other years

Tags: r, dataframe, row, na, long-format-data

I have a pretty large longitudinal data set ranging from 2014 to 2021. Most of the variables are available for every years. However there are a few variables that are available for 2014 and 2016, but not for 2015.  In these cases, I want to calculate the value for 2015 as the mean of the value from 2014 and 2016.

So the data structure looks as follows. Note this is extremely simplified, the data set has way more variables and observation. Also for each respondent there are rows for the other years as well (obviously), which I didnt write down here

| PID | Year | Var 1 | Var 2 | Var 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2014 | 10 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2015 | 15 | 8 | NA |
| 1 | 2016 | 12 | 6 | 4 |
| 2 | 2014 | 11 | 7 | 5 |
| 2 | 2015 | 16 | 3 | NA |
| 2 | 2016 | 14 | 5 | 9 |

PID is the id/number that identifies each respondent. Var1 and Var2 are available for every year, Var3 is only available in 2014 and 2015

What I want is this:

| PID | Year | Var 1 | Var 2 | Var 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2014 | 10 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2015 | 15 | 8 | 3 |
| 1 | 2016 | 12 | 6 | 4 |
| 2 | 2014 | 11 | 7 | 5 |
| 2 | 2015 | 16 | 3 | 7 |
| 2 | 2016 | 14 | 5 | 9 |

For Var3, instead of NA, the row for 2015 contains the mean of the value in 2014 and 2016.
How can I achieve this?

My first ideas was to adress the missing values in 2015 by `is.na()` but this would address all the NAs in the whole data set and not just the NAs in 2015 for Var2. How can I adress these NAs specifically, so that it a) only calculates the value for 2015 as mean of 2014 and 2016 for Var2 and b) only for those rows where PID is the same, so that values of different respondents do not get mixed up?

Comment: Look up the term "imputation", it's a well-documented process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking about is [imputation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imputation_(statistics)), where there are different methods for how to replace empty/null/`NA` values. One such method involves the regressed value based on one or more other non-empty variables.

I'm actually taking a little liberty with this ... you said "mean of 2014 and 2016", which in this case is going to be the same, but if for some reason you have 2014 and 2017 and are missing 2015-2016, then "mean" will be biased and be the same value for both 2015-2016. `approx`imation works well here.

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
quux %>%
  mutate(
    across(-Year, ~ coalesce(.x, approx(Year, .x, xout = Year)$y)),
    .by = PID
  )
#   PID Year Var 1 Var 2 Var 3
# 1   1 2014    10     2     2
# 2   1 2015    15     8     3
# 3   1 2016    12     6     4
# 4   2 2014    11     7     5
# 5   2 2015    16     3     7
# 6   2 2016    14     5     9
```

`coalesce` is logically the same as `ifelse(is.na(.x), approx(..)$y, .x)`, which means that if it is not `NA` then the original value will always be used. Frankly, we could likely just do

```r
... across(-Year, ~ approx(Year, .x, xout = Year)$y)
```

(removing the `coalesce`, always replacing all values) which still results in the same desired results. But since I don't know the ins and outs of your data, I thought I would be safer about the process.

## base R

```r
quux[,-(1:2)] <- lapply(
  quux[,-(1:2)],
  function(V) with(quux,
    ave(as.numeric(1:nrow(quux)), PID,
        FUN = function(i) ifelse(is.na(V[i]), approx(Year[i], V[i], xout=Year[i])$y, V[i]))
  )
)
quux
#   PID Year Var 1 Var 2 Var 3
# 1   1 2014    10     2     2
# 2   1 2015    15     8     3
# 3   1 2016    12     6     4
# 4   2 2014    11     7     5
# 5   2 2015    16     3     7
# 6   2 2016    14     5     9
```

While `dplyr` and friends have built-in grouping for transformations, in base R we need to use something like `ave` for non-aggregating by-group calculations.

- I manually exclude the columns we *don't* want to impute by using `-(1:2)`; it can just as easily be done by specifying which columns you *need* to impute, such as `quux[,3:5] <- lapply(quux[,3:5], ...)`.
- `ave` only works on one column (vector) at a time, so it's not possible to directly use both `Year` and (say) `Var 1` within it. Because of this, instead of telling `ave` the data is `Var 1`, we use row-indices as the grouped variable and use that internally to calculate on the correct indices of `Year` and the `Var #` variable.
- `ave` returns the same class as its first argument (regardless of what is returned), so we force the row-indices to be `numeric` instead of `integer`. It isn't clear if your data is `numeric` or `integer`, so you may be able to not use `as.numeric`, over to you.
- we *could* (without too much difficulty) craft our own `coalesce` function (similar to `dplyr::coalesce`, `data.table::fcoalesce`, and SQL's `COALESCE` functions) and replace much of the `ifelse` statement, but ... internally it would be doing much the same thing.

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(PID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Year = c(2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L), "Var 1" = c(10L, 15L, 12L, 11L, 16L, 14L), "Var 2" = c(2L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L), "Var 3" = c(2L, NA, 4L, 5L, NA, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  The imputation with `coalesce` is a great way to start. However, I want to do the imputation ONLY for the NAs in year 2015 and ONLY for the NAs in specified variables (reason is that NAs in 2015 are not due to biased non response but simply because certain items were not part of the questionare in 2015). Is there a way to implement this? I tried to write the conditions as an if-statement right behind `mutate()`, but I always get the error message: `the condition has length > 1`

Comment: Sure! I'm not at my computer, but something like `if_else(year == 2015, coalesce(...), .x)`

Comment: Thanks again! However I simply couldn't find a way for `coalesce ()` to work with the 
`if_else` statement. I tried `cal_new <- cal %>%
  mutate( if_else(year== 2015 & (colnames(cal) == Var2 | colnames(cal) == Var3), coalesce(.x, approx(Jahr, .x, xout = Jahr)$y), .x), .by = PID)` and what I get is: `Error in mutate() .... Caused by Error: object '.x' not found`

Comment: I never said to put `if_else` at the top, I said to put `coalesce` inside of it, still inside of the `across`. Recognize that 99.9% of the time, any expression in `mutate` must be named, either to add or replace (/update) a column. Try `quux %>% mutate(across(-Year, ~ if_else(Year == 2015, coalesce(.x, approx(Year, .x, xout = Year)$y), .x)), .by = PID)`.

Comment: Thanks again, now I finally got it! I also noticed the second part of the `if_else` condition was bs and caused some trouble. But I had to find a way to only apply it to column Var2 and Var3, so I changed it to `across(c(Var2, Var3), ~ if_else(Year== 2015, ....` and now it works just fine. Thanks so much for your help and your patience!